# String Variables in XML

Tags: python, xml, django, twilio

In Python 3 you can insert string variables into a string like so:

`print("Hi %s how are you?" % name)`

How would you do the same thing in an XML string in a view? Something like:

`<Response><Message>Hi %s how are you?</Message></Response> % name`

Note that I'm doing this in a view (as a response to a [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) request) rather than a template, so I can't simply insert a template variable.

Comment: How are you generating that XML at the moment? Can you share your code?

Comment: @philnash exactly like you see it. It's hardcoded. `xml = <Response> <Message>xml</Message></Response>`

Comment: If you are generating the xml in python you can do `xml = "<Response> <Message>%s</Message></Response>" % "xml" ` like in your print example.

Comment: @PacoH. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I do not recommend hardcoding XML responses as you can easily make mistakes. If you're using Python, then I recommend you use the [Twilio Python](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python) module's [TwiML creation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message?code-sample=code-simple-sending-of-sms&code-language=py&code-sdk-version=6.x) utilities. Then you can do the string formatting with the text for the XML and let the library handle the elements. Like:

```
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import Message, MessagingResponse

response = MessagingResponse()
text = "Hi %s how are you?" % name
response.message(text)

print(response)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Ah, didn't know there was a package for that! That looks a lot cleaner. Much obliged.

Comment: Cool, have a go with it and make sure to mark this answer as correct if it helps out. Thanks!